# MVVM with Room and LiveData - How to get List from LiveData

Tags: java, android

I am creating a TODO List application where the user can add tasks to do. There are a few categories of tasks. And I have the following situation:

```
        viewModelMainActivity = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelMainActivity.class);
        viewModelMainActivity.getAllJob().observe(this, new Observer<List<Task>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {

                if(tasks.size() == 0) {

                    linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                taskAdapter.setTasks(tasks);
            }
        });
```

I get a list of tasks from the job category and from other categories. Thanks to `LiveData` in `ViewModel`, the list will be updated when a task is added or deleted.

In addition, I have a spinner that allows you to select a category of tasks to display tasks from a selected category.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {

        //How to get a List?
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
}
```

How can I display a list of tasks from a selected category since the data type in `ViewModel` is `LiveData`, and only data in the form of `List` is obtained in the `onChanged()` method?

Answer (score 0):

A look at your ViewModel would be nice, but from what I undertand its that you type in your viewmodel is just liveData.

Well in your ViewModel, you can set an other type to a liveData

EX :

```
String toto = LiveData<String>()
```

Answer (score 0):

First tell the view model about the spinner selection and let viewmodel decide what to do

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position long id) {
    viewModelMainActivity.onCategorySelected(position);
}
```

Inside viewModel

```
public void onCategorySelected(int categoryId){
  TODO 1 you should have two live data one to hold all the tasks and the other one for the category tasks
  TODO 2 here filter the tasks based on category and the updated the live data
}
```

Comment: How can I filter this data?

Comment: based on the task's cateogry id each task should have category id based on that you can filter the tasks

Answer (score 0):

LiveData from Room always returns you a completely new list. You have to replace your old List with a new one.

Do not have LiveData from Room in your ViewModel